# Mysql workbench, introducir los mismo datos en varios esquemas y otra duda

Tags: mysql, sql, nodejs

Estoy recién empezando en mysql y estamos usando mysql workbench, tengo algunas dudas. ¡Gracias a todos!

Cuando inicio mysql shell me sale "MySQL JS" aunque puedo cambiar a "MySQL sql". No puedo ni cargar ni usar la base de datos con el JS, al menos no sé cómo hacerlo y en cambio, en el modo sql no tengo problema. ¿Alguien me puede explicar la diferencia? ¿Y cómo puedo cargar y usar una base de datos con JS?

Por otra parte, cuando trabajo en el workbench e introduzco datos, sale la siguiente sintáxis:

INSERT INTO `sakila`.`actor` (`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES ('Juan', 'Ruíz');

La cuestión es que si pongo sakila.actor, solo puedo introducir la información en el esquema de sakila, ¿habría alguna forma de introducir la línea para cualquier esquema y en la tabla actor?

De nuevo, gracias!

Comment: Que es lo que queres hacer con Mysql? Insertar en diferentes BD en la tabla actor ?

Comment: Quiero poder insertar en cualquier base de datos, sin tener en cuenta el nombre de la misma, en una tabla que se llame actor, esos valores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respecto a la segunda parte de tu pregunta, es posible insertar en cualquier esquema, en la tabla actor? Sí se puede, sin embargo, requiere algo de trabajo.

No sé cómo consultarlas en MySQL, pero, en SQLServer las tablas de sistema pueden darte la información que buscas. Lo que puedes hacer es:

1-. Obtener los nombres de los esquemas que han sido creado por los usuarios a través de las tablas de sistema.

2-. Creas un cursor para iterar sobre los nombres.

3-. Con sql dinámico, en el Insert, deberás reemplazar el esquema por el valor del cursor

Por ejemplo en Transact-Sql:

```
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(MAX);
set @sql = N' 
   Insert into ' +@nombreEsquema+ '.Usuario (first_name,last_name)
   Values('+@first_name+','+@last_name+')'
```

Y luego se ejecuta el sql dinámico con :

```
 sp_executesql @sql
```

Para cada row del cursor.

Nuevamente, eso es T-SQL. Tendrás que buscar cómo hacerlo en MySQL.

Recuerda evaluar si la tabla existe en el esquema. Si no existe, habrá un error. **Tal vez quieras obtener de las tablas de sistema los esquemas donde sí exista una tabla llamada Actor**

Tu pregunta es algo extraña, pero ya he necesitado algo así. Espero esto te ayude y apunte en la dirección correcta